# How to do load balancing with nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I need to use server as load balancer and web server at the same time.

Here is my nginx config for website:

```
upstream load_balancer {
    least_conn;
    server localhost;
        #server srv2.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://load_balancer;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use one server as load balancer and web server at the same time? How to do it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: do not use least_conn; just keep default round-robin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible;

You can just create virtual host with a different port.

`(Load Balancer [Port 80] + Virtualhost [Port 81])` So it will in effect have one server listening on two ports; one serves a web page and one load balances.

Then when linking the website on the server to the load balancer you would use the IP `localhost:81`

You can create the local website by typing:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

Then pasting (May need to edit according to needs.)

```
 server {
        listen   81;

        root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're very welcome :-)